# After I installed python3.7.1, the input method stops working. What's the matter?

Tags: python3, input-method, fcitx

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic. Yesterday I built python 3.7.1 from source and `sudo make install`. The process didn't end successfully and had some problems with `lsb_release`. I guessed it is because the installer pointed `python3` to `python3.7` and `lsb_release` uses `python3` in shell bang so I changed the shell bang to `python3.6`, which is the one came with Ubuntu. After the hack I installed again and succeeded. Since this overrides the default `python3`, some problems arise. To fix them I changed `lsb_release` back to its origin, but the input method remained broken. Now when I switch to `zh` and want to use `sogou pinyin`, nothing but a blue little box shows up with "keyboard - English (US)".

Before I installed `python3.7` everything works fine. I doubted it is the installation that disables the input method. I manually (and carefully) uninstalled `python3.7`, removing all things that show up in `locate python3.7`. But the problem remains. Since changing python version globally can produce unexpected effect, I guess it must be.

What can I do? I am using fcitx.

Comment: I am not sure how to fix problems with `fcitx`.

Comment: Guys! I fixed it! I checked the `/usr/bin/` and found some broken symbolic links including `python3` being an actual executable (it ought to be a link) and I fixed them. After that the input method begins to work again! Thanks for giving me the chance to articulate the problem and solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Although the reasons remain unclear, I manage to fix it. I simply restored python-related executable in `/usr/bin/` to the state before the installation took effect. In other words, back to the default 3.6 settings. I was attempted to reinstall the system python but stopped because the things `apt remove` will clear were all critical things and doing that would destroy the desktop GUI entirely. Now I learn that changing system python is definitely a bad idea. Something like `pyenv` will help.